# Powershell searching for specific description on computers

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

in my organisation  the "description" attribute on computers automatically updates who logged on last and when, so it looks like this "OU,USERNAME,DATE AND TIME"
Example:
IT-afdelingen,chrijen,28-07-2021 08:16:12

i want to search for the USERNAME in the description so i can see what pc the users logged on last.

---

this does not work because it seems like i cant but $hanne between **

```
$hanne = "dthamyl","chrijen","bjokjer"
foreach ($item in $hanne) {Get-ADComputer -filter "description -like '*$hanne*'"}
```

---

if i put the usernames in the variable like this it works

```
    $hanne = "*dthamyl*","*chrijen*","*bjokjer*"
```

basically i want to take a bunch of displaynames and find their usernames and use the usernames to see which computer they use

```
$navne = "DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME","DISPLAYNAME"

$usernames = foreach ($user in $navne) {get-aduser -filter "displayname -eq '$user'" | select samaccountname}

foreach ($item in $usernames) {

Get-ADComputer -Filter "description -like '$item'"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the Description property contains the SamAccountName of the logged on user and you want to find these computers based on an array of SamAccountNames of the users.

In that case, this should get you going:

```
# create an array of user SamAccountnames to look for in the Description property of the computers
$navne = "dthamyl","chrijen","bjokjer"

# create a regex from all usernames in $navne combined with the regex 'OR' character
# for safety, use [regex]::Escape() on each to escape characters that have special meaning in regex.
$users = ($navne | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

# get the computer objects and use a Where-Object clause to filter on computers
# where the Description matches the users regex
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Description | Where-Object { $_.Description -match $users } | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                  @{Name = 'User'; Expression = { ($_.Description -split ',')[1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much :) i didnt end up using it exactly how you did because im still quite bad at powershell, but i used some of your ideas to get it to work.. it ended up looking like this #array of DisplayNames
$navn = "displayname","displayname","displayname"
#array of SamAccountnames found from the DisplayNames
$navne = foreach ($item in $navn) {get-aduser -filter "displayname -eq '$item'" | select samaccountname}

foreach ($user in $navne) {
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties description | Where-Object { $_.description -match $user.samaccountname} | select name, description }